# neo4j create list of edges

Tags: scala, neo4j, query-optimization

I have a stream of *pairs* ,  where **id** is numberic id of the node, and **ids** is the list of ids of the adjacent nodes. 
I use this query to upsert nodes from such stream:

```
WITH ${ids.mkString("[", ",", "]")} as ids
UNWIND ids as u2id
MERGE (u1:User {Id:${id}})
MERGE (u2:User {Id:u2id})
CREATE UNIQUE p = (u1) - [:FRIEND] -> (u2)
```

And i have index on Id label

```
CREATE INDEX ON :User(Id)
```

The length of ids list is about 100-200 in average.

Now there are ~60 millions of nodes and mil. of edges in the database. Speed of upserting is about *pairs* per second. Neo4j running on dedicated machine with Core i5, 28Gb RAM and 2Tb WD Black.

I wonder how upserting query can be optimized or any tip to improve hardware.

Comment: Couple of questions ... 1) Is the stream constant (it's not that you could have all the updates in a CSV file say and do a LOAD CSV) ? 2) Is the User(Id) merely an index or a unique constraint ? 3) Are you actually creating new Users too (MERGE implies that) ? 4) Can you add the expanded image of a PROFILE of one such execution ?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, 1) yes it's true stream 2) index 3) yes, creating 4) unfortunately database is inaccessible at now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These progressive changes should make the query faster.

1. **Perform `MERGE` of `u1` just once**

   By moving the `MERGE` of `u1` before the `UNWIND`, it will only be executed once (instead of once per `u2id` value).

   ```
   MERGE (u1:User {Id:${id}})
   WITH u1, ${ids.mkString("[", ",", "]")} as ids
   UNWIND ids as u2id
   MERGE (u2:User {Id:u2id})
   CREATE UNIQUE (u1)-[:FRIEND]->(u2)
   ```
2. **In addition, use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE UNIQUE`**

   Your relationship creation use case should be satisfiable by `MERGE` as well as `CREATE UNIQUE` (since you ensure that both endpoints exist beforehand). In my profiling, I see that `MERGE` uses fewer DB hits (your mileage may vary, depending on your DB characteristics and neo4j version).

   ```
   MERGE (u1:User {Id:${id}})
   WITH u1, ${ids.mkString("[", ",", "]")} as ids
   UNWIND ids as u2id
   MERGE (u2:User {Id:u2id})
   MERGE (u1)-[:FRIEND]->(u2)
   ```

Comment: thank for advice, move MERGE outside of UNWID really speed up query. But when number of nodes become ~100 mil. Node4j process begins to swap and speed decreased dramatically, so we decide to write to files and process them later :(